# Fastest possible space-probe

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, satellites

What is the fastest possible velocity a space probe can achieve using planetary orbits? 
 has there been such a planetary alignment in the past 100 years?

Comment: Are you talking about using a [gravitational slingshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist) or are you asking how fast a space probe could orbit a planet without falling out of orbit?

Comment: More details are required. A probe moving at X km/s can be accelerated with a planetary slingshot to X+1 km/s. A probe moving at Y km/s can be accelerated to Y+1 km/s. A gravity assist will always let you go faster - how fast is the probe going in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I meant a gravitational slingshot

Comment: The Helios probes were roughly 250000km/h when they passed the sun, if I remember correctly. How fast could they have been if the planets were aligned more favourably?

Comment: Similar to [What are the practical limits of gravitational assists ?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/what-are-the-practical-limitations-of-gravitational-assists) on Space Exploration SE.  This question is probably more suitable for that SE.